# Array of locations in elasticserach spatial query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to this elastic search concept i can't find a solution for my problem. suppose consider the following query.

```
GET banknew/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 8.722479,
        "lon": 78.13047
      },
      "distance": "5km"
    }
  }
}
```

This will gave me the result. The above query is for 1 location(means 1 lat, lng). But i have to get the result for multiple locations(means for 2 or more lat, lng). What i tried is

```
GET banknew/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "location": [{
        "lat": 8.722479,
        "lon": 78.13047
      },{
        "lat": 8.722479,
        "lon": 78.13047
      }      ],
      "distance": "5km"
    }
  }
}
```

I have to get the result of points within 5km for 1st location and also 2nd location.

But i am receiving error `"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed". Whether its possible. Please guide me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use another geo_distance filter and wrap it up in a [bool filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html#query-dsl-bool-filter).

If you are searching result at 5km from first location OR second location, add it in the `should` clause.

Try something like this :

```
GET banknew/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "5km",
            "location": {
              "lat": lat1,
              "lon": lon1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "5km",
            "location": {
              "lat": lat2,
              "lon": lon2
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks... 1 clarification is that whether it will give result for both lat, long. That is should get the 5km points for 1st lat, lng and for 2nd lat,lng.. Suppose consider for 1st lat, lng there 3 points within 5km and 4 points for 2nd lat, lng, then the result should be 7(total)..

Comment: That should be the case with the above query: you will retrieve both points from 5km around first or second point.